# Syntax error with graphQL "Expected Name..."

Tags: graphql

here is my code:

```
mutation CreateReviewForBook($ISBN: String!, $author: String!, $content: String!) {
  createBookReview(ISBN: $ISBN, author: $author, content: $content) {
    date
    author
    content
    status
  }
}

{
  "ISBN": "0743273567",
  "author": "Robert B.",
  "content": "Great book!"
}
```

here is the question:

Using GraphQL, write a mutation named createBookReview that returns the fields: date, author, content, and status.

The arguments to the mutation should be the following:

> ISBN = "0743273567"
> author = "Robert B."
> content = "Great book!"

Error:

> {   "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "ISBN"",
> "extensions": {
> "category": "graphql"
> },
> "locations": [
> {
> "line": 11,
> "column": 3
> }
> ]
> }   ] }

Can someone explain why am I getting this error?

Comment: Anyone have ideas how to fix this error ?

Comment: Are you trying to send this whole thing as a query? Your variables should be passed as arguments, not included in the second half of the query like this.